# Open(), Close(), and Read() applied to Linux pipe file descriptiors

Tags: c++, linux, pipe

This is probably a simple question, but I want to confirm my understanding of these functions - and possibly clarified if I'm completely wrong about them.

Here's what's going on:

I have a multi-threaded program that is passing data via pipes, using the unix `pipe()` function. Basically, two threads can write to the pipe (they're synchronized of course), and only one can read from the pipe.

From my understanding, the `read()` command will attempt to read `x` number of bytes from the passed file descriptor parameter, and it will return 0 if `EOF` is reached.

The number of bytes I write to the pipe is variable, so this presents a minor difficulty when reading from the pipe. I believe I read somewhere that using `close(my_pipe_file_descriptor)` throws in `EOF`. If this is the case, `read()` will return once it hits `EOF` - which would be great.

If what I said above is correct - in reference to how `close()` and `read()` works - I have a question.

If I call `close(my_pipe_file_descriptor)`, is the pipe destroyed, making any future calls to `open(my_pipe_file_descriptor)` invalid?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

For the question about `close`, yes it destroys the pipe, you can no longer use it in the process where you closed it. If you want to use a new pipe you have to create one again. If you close the write-end of the pipe, then the read end is still valid, allowing the reader to read until all data has been received. That last bit means that the writer doesn't have to wait until it knows the reader has received all data (it generally can't anyway), but just write whatever data it wants and then just close the its end of the pipe.

As your understanding of the `read` function, it's basically correct. You ask it to read a certain number of bytes, and it will read *up to* that number of bytes. It may read less, you have to check the returned value to learn exactly how much it has read. That goes not only for pipes, but for sockets and files as well.

I recommend you read the [official POSIX references](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

- [`pipe`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
- [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)
- [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)

And for completeness sake (even though it can't be used to open or create anonymous pipes):

- [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)

There are also thousands of example on how to use pipes if you just search a little.

Comment: Another good reference is [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book. Also, knowing about multiplexing syscalls like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the older [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)...) is very useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was helpful. Another quick question, the documentation says that read() will return 0 if it hits EOF. This feels like a "hackish" way of doing it, but could I simply write EOF to the pipe as a form of flow control? That is, EOF is being used to indicate that a thread's write is complete.

Comment: Never mind. I forgot that EOF is platform dependent in the sense that there is no ASCII character code - however, I can get around this by looking for a special character that I define.

Comment: My pipe is cutting multi byte characters in half. How can I prevent that?

Comment: @JRowan Then you're either not reading your multi-byte characters correctly, or not writing them correctly. If by multi-byte characters you mean `wchar_t` characters, then remember that the actual type (and therefore the size) of `wchar_t` is implementation specific, if the writer and reader have different definitions of `wchar_t` then they won't work well together. Please post a question about this issue, providing a [mcve] of both writer and reader programs.